# Trying to Use Solver with Different Constraints

Tags: microsoft-excel, solver

I want to give instruction to an Excel to give me a sum of certain amount by changing only Quantities. In the pictures, let say I want to get the sum of 250 (cell H16) by changing cells G5:G15. I can do that by using Solver, but I also need to include some restrictions or rules for Excel to use. First of all, my quantities have to be integer numbers. Secondly, I want an Excel to return numbers for all changing cells (G5:G15). Sometimes Excel does not fill all selected changing cells and returns numbers only for 3 cells.

Any help or idea would be appreciated. Many thanks in advance.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYbUk.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is that variables should be integer and non-negative you may get the solution in which part of the variables is equal to 0. You may add another restriction that the variables should be `>=1`, but in case of small values of your goal this leeds to unreasonable results.
See the screenshots.
[image: Solver1]
[image: Solver2]

Answer (score 0):

To implement constraints in Excel solver, those need to be implemented as formulas between the inputs the solver can change and the result that is controlled.

To ensure every quantity has a minimum, you need to insert an intermediary column, eg **filtered quantity** in `D2`, with the constraint implemented as formula: ; where `C2` is the **raw quantity** cell the Solver must change.

Then use this **filtered quantity** cell, instead of **raw quantity**, to compute your **Price** formula in `E2`.

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Product | Unit Price | Raw quantity | Filtered quantity |
| 2 | X | 22.84 | 54 | 54 `=TRUNC(MAX(1,C2))` |